# Find specified value from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get some help for the query below, I tried to use 'exist & not exist' but it has just returned mistaken values..

The table is like:

```
Column
------
1500.50.x
1500.50.a
1500.50.b
1985.12.x
1812.2345.a
1812.2345.x
```

What I want to do is ; if the 1500.50 has x and a and b, then just get 1500.50.a and 1500.50.b,

If there is nothing other than .x, then just get 1500.50.x

The output must be like;

```
1500.50.x
1500.50.a
1985.12.x
1812.2345.a
```

My code is:

```
select docnumbers 
from #all a where docnumbers
LIKE '%.X' 
and not exists 
(select 1 from #all aa where a.docnumbers=aa.docnumbers and aa.docnumbers LIKE '%.A' OR docnumbers LIKE '%.B' OR docnumbers LIKE '%.C'  ) 

union all 

select docnumbers
from #all
where docnumbers LIKE '%.A' OR docnumbers LIKE '%.B' OR docnumbers LIKE '%.C'
```

Comment: You say "_if the 1500.50 has x and a and b, then just get 1500.50.a and 1500.50.b_", but the wanted result contains 1500.50.a and 1500.50.x...

Comment: Will any other letters than a, b and x show up?

Comment: @HoneyBadger ; just added.
@jarlh; lets consider firstly group by numbers like 1500.50 or 1812.2345 or 1985.12.
1500.50 has a,x and b so 1500.50.a and 1500.50.b must be in the output, for the 1985.12 there must be only 1985.12.x cause of there is only x in that number, for 1812.2345 must be 1812.2345.a
same as 1500.12 ,cause it has x and a.

Comment: What is the current output? Why is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that

```
SELECT docnumbers
FROM t1 x
WHERE docnumbers LIKE '%x'
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM t1 likexbutnotx
     WHERE likexbutnotx.docnumbers != x.docnumbers
       AND likexbutnotx.docnumbers LIKE replace(x.docnumbers, 'x', '_'))
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM t1 notx
WHERE docnumbers NOT LIKE '%x'
ORDER BY docnumbers
```

Comment: appreciate! worked as I precisely wish (;